# Auto refresh code in HTML using meta tags

Tags: html, meta

I'm trying to refresh the same page but it isn't working. This is my HTML code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML in 10 Simple Steps or Less</title>
    <meta http-equiv=”refresh” content=”5" />
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ooops sorry, the question was because of the odd weide quote likish marks. I accidentally corrected it. I'm tied and my arse is numb, if thats any consolation

Comment: Can you revert that edit? Took me a while to figure out why his code didn't work since you fixed it.

Answer (score 231):

It looks like you probably pasted this (or used a word processor like MS Word) using a kind of double-quotes that are not recognized by the browser. Please check that your code uses actual double-quotes like this one `"`, which is different from the following character: `”`

Replace the meta tag with this one and try again:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify when to stop auto-refreshing. For example, if the page is left up accidently I wouldn't want it to keep auto-refreshing indefinitely.

Comment: @Rod Then you would need a system that "detects" how long your computer have been there. localStorage that stores a variable every reload, some server programmed system that stops you from reloading by deleting / not returning the reload script, ...
In other words, not with the meta tag code posted in this answer.

Comment: Bonus points for detecting such a subtle error in the original question!

Answer (score 45):

You're using smart quotes. That is, instead of standard quotation marks (`"`), you are using curly quotes (`”`). This happens automatically with Microsoft Word and other word processors to make things look prettier, but it also mangles HTML.  Make sure to code in a plain text editor, like Notepad or [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML in 10 Simple Steps or Less</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"> <!-- See the difference? -->
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 40):

The quotes you use are the issue:

```
<meta http-equiv=”refresh” content=”5" >
```

You should use the `"`

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

Answer (score 26):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600; url=index.php">
```

600 is the amount of seconds between refresh cycles.

Comment: You should mention that automatic refresh can be disabled in some browsers

Answer (score 15):

**Try this:**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL= your url">
```

**or**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this tag. This will refresh the `index.html` page every 30 seconds.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30;url=index.html">
```