# Refresh HTML page automatically

Tags: html

I need to refresh and HTML page automatically.

If I put the following in my HEAD tag it seems to do the trick:

```
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
     <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
     <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
   </head>
```

I am wondering if others have had experiences where it does not work.

Thanks

Comment: Read this question and the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711888/auto-refresh-code-in-html-using-meta-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are known problems where this will not work with some versions of IE. There is a kind of hack where you put a second head section containing the appropriate meta tag, at the end of the HTML document.

Comment: Thanks Kev. For the known issues, if the user does refresh it should refresh the page,correct?

Answer (score 3):

```
Try this tag. 

     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900">
    </head>
```