# How to add auto-refresh to this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh

My name is John. (Yes I know very useful information :)) I'm create a new statistics in php and my Javascript code look like

```
var req;

function hide() {
    for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        element = document.getElementById(arguments[i]);
        if (element) {
            element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
}

function show() {
    for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        element = document.getElementById(arguments[i]);
        if (element) {
            element.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }
}

function loadXMLDoc(url) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange;
        req.open("GET", url, true);
        req.send(null);

        hide('lastposts');
        show('lastposts_update');

    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        if (req) {
            req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange;
            req.open("GET", url, true);
            req.send();

            hide('lastposts');
            show('lastposts_update');
        }
    }
}

function processReqChange() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        element = document.getElementById('lastposts_text');
        if (element) {
            if (req.status == 200) {
                element.innerHTML = req.responseText;
            } else {
                element.innerHTML = "Error " + req.status + "<br />" + req.statusText;
            }
        }

        hide('lastposts_update');
        show('lastposts');
    } else {
        var status_message = new Array(
        "The query is not initialized", 
        "The query is created", 
        "The query is sent", 
        "The query is processed"
        );

        element_status = document.getElementById('status');
        if (element_status) {
            element_status.innerHTML = status_message[req.readyState];
        }
    }
}
```

and HTML output

```
<div id="lastposts_update" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <img src="images/refresh.gif" alt="wait">&nbsp;
    <span id="status"></span>
</div>

<div id="lastposts" style="z-index: 2;">
<a href="" onclick="loadXMLDoc('{URL}'); return false;">
<img src="images/refresh.gif" alt="refresh" border="0"></a>

<span id="lastposts_text">
{IMPORT_NEW_STATISTICS}
</span>

</div>
```

How modified this code and add auto-refreshing and remove manual refresh?
Can you help me? I'll be very grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the similar QA [Auto refresh code in HTML using meta tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711888/auto-refresh-code-in-html-using-meta-tags)

try to put the following code

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

into HTML header tag.