# Repeat PHP script included in website

Tags: php, timer

I've searched all around for a solution to my problem, but I can't seem to understand where to put the solution.

I'm creating a webpage which will show information from different API sources, and I would like all the information to be updated on different intervals.

I've seen the "while(true) { sleep(5); }" solution, but it just freezes the website, preventing it to load.

Lets say my webpage looks like this:

```
<body>
<?php

echo "hello world";

?>
</body>
```

How can I make the php script repeat on certain intervals?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to use Javascript and AJAX to achieve that.

Comment: Are you kind enough to link a tutorial please?

Comment: Type in "ajax tutorial" on google and click on the very first link.

Comment: Nobody here will write the script that you want for you. Do some reading, write some code, and come back with a specific question about an issue that you run into.

Comment: Migth be as simple as putting a refresh tag in the html header. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711888/auto-refresh-code-in-html-using-meta-tags

Comment: @TylerCollins, I didn't expect that either.

Comment: @AndréSchild I tried that, but it didn't give me the result I wanted. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question you have is basically about the use of client side and server side scripting. A language like php runs on the server and not on the computer of the client, the user. Therefore, it cannot change anything on the webpage as soon as it has been sent off to the user. That is where client-side scripts come in play.

The server can send a script in a language like javascript to the user if a link to the script is included in the html. Those scripts will be executed on the user's browser. With an combination of Javascript and AJAX (stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML, and is not a language btw), you can load a php-file into your page. You can use javascript to let AJAX do that every x miliseconds with the function 
    `setInterval()`

A few links and tutorials:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll read this and figure it out eventually.