# Java based tool - bypassing refresh prompt?

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax

At work, we use a specific web based program to keep track incidents. However, we need to refresh the page for us to see the new incidents. Hiccup is that we have a prompt to confirm the reload, which will annoyingly pop-out, rendering any Firefox auto-refresh add-on useless.

Screenshot: http://imgur.com/ToVz5jM

P.S. Noob, please have patience :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto refresh code in HTML using meta tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711888/auto-refresh-code-in-html-using-meta-tags).

Comment: What kind of prompt? The prompt that says that you are about to resubmit a posted form? And what is the programming angle - where can you program something - this question is tagged with an array of tags but it's not clear what program you can change.

Comment: "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - Data you have entered may not be saved. Leave Page / Stay on page"

Pop up shows in all browsers, but is based on java, as stated by wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximo_(MRO) ;). Main post edited and uploaded a screenshot of the pop-up, if that helps.

Comment: Sounds like you should change your ticket system^^ Check out Zendesk or JIRA. One of them will fit your needs.

Comment: At least for Firefox there may be something there:  http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/how-to-stop-ask-to-confirm-leaving-pop-up-in-firefox.365208/