# How do I setInterval an Express-app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, setinterval

Been googling for a bit, trying out stuff and coming up with all sorts of weird solutions to my problem without really getting anywhere. My question is, how would I setInterval my express.js-application to let it run once every 30s?

The reasoning for this is that I have a bunch of variables that change every ~30s and I need to re-render the page in order for these to show up. The "solutions" that I have come up with hits the EADDRINUSE error since I am trying to create a new server on the same port as the old one, so I understand that there is something that needs to be done here to avoid that, but what?

If anyone wants to know what I have tried, I've tried process.exit (and let PM2 restart my app), setInterval, purposely crashed my app to let PM2 restart and even begun rewriting everything to let web sockets run back and forth between client and server, but I feel like this is over-complicating (maybe) the issue, as a standard setInterval would solve it all, if I just understood how.

Below is my express-script:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var ejs = require('ejs');
var config = require('./config');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile);

app.get("/", function(req, res){
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

async(function(variables) {
    res.render('index', 
    {
    // stuff to render
    });
});
function async(callback) {
    // several variables...
    callback(variables);
}


});

app.listen(config.port, "0.0.0.0");
```

Comment: Are you trying the `setInterval` at the server side? That won't work. Either set it at the client side and reload the data upon the tick or use the socket.io and push the data from the server to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things you want to google for are: comet, long-pulling, web sockets, [event sourcing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource).

Basically this is how I would work on this task:

1. Have a global state in your web server, simple setInterval to update it and setInterval to constantly do AJAX call to the web page.
2. Use [web sockets](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) and instead of `setInterval(AJAX)` push new state to the client.

Second approach is faster and preferable, but may require fallback if you need to support older browsers.

Comment: Thank you! This will give me a good start at least. I will set this as my accepted answer. :)

Comment: Is it alright to do a follow-up question to an accepted answer, or should I create a new question for it?

Comment: Here is my question:
I have had great success with websockets, but am stuck in a situation where I am unsure how to separate message-events. How does the client know which event should go to messageA/B in the below websocket onmessage? Is this set on the server, and if so, how?

```Client:
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
messageA(event.data);
messageB(event.data);
};`

`Server:
ws.send(JSON.stringify(messageA), function () {...});
.....
ws.send(JSON.stringify(messageA), function () {...});
```

Comment: One of the links I have in my answer is to socket.io it is in their examples. You can do it with plain  WS. Add property  `message` to the object you send and do eg switch case on other side.

Comment: It sure did, thanks a lot. I have now succeeded with what I wanted to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is the correct approach? Doesn't seem the correct one to me. I wouldn't do it.

You have to set the refreshing function on the client using some JS script(to auto refresh the page or update the values using AJAX/WS) or the equivalent [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711888/auto-refresh-code-in-html-using-meta-tags).

Comment: I am not sure it is the correct approach, but I can't really see how else I would do it. I have a couple of my variables inside the app.get-function that will not be updated unless I rerun the express.js script, hence why I need it to re-run.