# Is there a way to provide simultaneous access to a webserver script?

Tags: php, json, database

I set up an apache2 server with php on my raspberry pi. The php code inside my script receives JSON saves it in memory and then echoes out what it received. In my client when a button is pressed it sends the aforementioned JSON which after the server returns the result changes the color of the button. What I'm trying to do is have 2 clients with the same button I send the POST request from the 1st client and refresh the 2nd client and then the 2nd client reflects the change the 1st client posted.

This doesn't work though, I'm probably using the wrong tool. I could start using a database, but eventually I would like to implement something that would require a LOT of writes and reads and wouldn't need to be stored for very long. Is there a different server side scripting language that would better suit what I'm trying to do, or is a database my only option?

EDIT:

The reason I'm using http is because it's a game client that doesn't support ipv6 sockets or translation, so I would ideally like to use the underlying http transport. I have some code running on my server and it works like I want it to, but what I don't understand is how to POST data that any client could retrieve.

```
<?php
$stream = fopen('php://memory','r+');
fwrite($stream, file_get_contents('php://input',true));
fseek($stream,0);
$data = json_decode($stream);
echo stream_get_contents($data);
?>
```

Is it something on Apaches side separating incoming requests? Part of my problem is that I don't know server side lingo. I want to say it's something with php being concurrent or something with threads, but would need to do more research.

I'm going to look into socket.io, but basically how can I POST some data to some location that anybody can access? Right now the only client that can access the data is the one that posted it.

Comment: Wouldn't [Socket.io](https://socket.io) be a better system here? You could have a head-end server that relays JSON data from one to another, that's a pretty common use case.

Comment: A little unclear exactly what you're trying to do. Something about a button and requests are sent between two servers? Can you re explain the situation in a more simple manner, and possibly provide some code if you have it.

Comment: HTTP is a request-response system, you cannot do what you want strictly within its confines. You need to implement something client-side with javascript that updates the browser with new information, and something server-side to either respond to poll requests for changes, or handle a [WebSocket](http://socketo.me/).

Comment: Can clients auto-refresh (using header like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711888/auto-refresh-code-in-html-using-meta-tags)?  If you need something "event driven" type, other comments below are better.

Answer (score 0):

You don't currently have a persistent connection from client to server (e.g. WebSockets), which is the crux of your problem: when Client 1 changes the button, the server has no way to tell Client 2 about the change. You could have the clients poll the server periodically and check for state changes, but this may not scale well or support low latency.

The question is pretty open ended as-is, but you probably could probably benefit from some persistent process that maintains client connections and state.

Answer (score 0):

if your application clients and server are intended to be running in a lan or their IP adress can be public (not behind nat) you may make them periodically tell the server where they are (ip) using simple socket and when they have a message the server will notify them by socket 
connection and at that point only they retrieve the message from the server using HTTP request as usual
its even better instead of periodically to tell the server about the new IP address only when it changes 
do the above if you are learning and experimenting and for production or serious school project use websocket