# How to force an android web app to force refresh on each open?

Tags: android, caching, web-applications

I have a very simple android web app pinned to the home screen. As I use the app, which is a simple to-do manager, from multiple places it happens that I add some to-dos from the computer, but I check them from phone. The problem is, whenever the app is already loaded and I open it from the home screen the content is not refreshed.

Is there a way to force reload every time I open the app? I tried to insert some `meta http-equiv=cache-control` to `index.html` or putting onload, onfocus, ... events to html body, but neither of them helped.

The `manifest.json` and `index.html` are nothing fancy, JS is populating container DIV from server through AJAX requests.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
  "name": "ToDoMan",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "../media/favicon-192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "theme_color": "#004c8b",
  "background_color": "#0277bc",
  "display": "standalone"
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="192x192" href="media/favicon-192.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="css_js/manifest.json">
<link href="css_js/todoman.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script src="css_js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="css_js/jquery.detect_swipe.js"></script>
<script src="css_js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <div id="loader"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out, you can check if the page is visible, so you can bind an event listener to it:

```
function handleVisibilityChange(){
  if(document.visibilityState == "visible"){
    load_container();
  }
}

document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', handleVisibilityChange);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [Auto refresh code in HTML using meta tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711888/auto-refresh-code-in-html-using-meta-tags)

Try `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">`, but this will refresh every second.

You might try with different redirect URL `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=app.html">`

Comment: I knew about this option, but I don't want automatic refresh.

Comment: How about adding a refresh button as mentioned in https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/
`document.getElementById('butRefresh').addEventListener('click', function() {
    app.updateForecasts();
  });`

You might leave out the refresh button just add update() function to the scripts.js

Comment: Hi Misi, I already solved this yesterday ;) but thanks anyway