# R: reload google chrome URL if already loaded

Tags: r, google-chrome, browser

I am using an Rscript to load an .html file with Google Chrome via `browseURL("myfile.html")`. However, I would like the Rscript to first check if the URL is already open in Chrome, and if so, just reload the URL. I don't want it to open the URL in a new Chrome tab. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Would an option be to close Chrome, and then open a new one instance? This would do nothing if it is not open, and and open a new version if the other closes.

Comment: @mhovd If there's no other work around that could do the trick, yes

Comment: I would add reload already in html file. if its open, the it would reloads every few minutes. you will find useful information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711888/auto-refresh-code-in-html-using-meta-tags

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. In practice however, the Rscript also produces the html file (it is a report generated via Rmarkdown), so I also need to be able to run the Rscript each time I want to update the html file.

Comment: As a workaround: There are several browser extensions available to prevent duplicated tabs. See [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/duplicate-tab-helper/oaceoebbkmkgfjhmngdinoclnionlgoh) or [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clutter-free-prevent-dupl/iipjdmnoigaobkamfhnojmglcdbnfaaf).

Comment: This indeed could be a workaround if no solution is found. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Are you using Windows, macOS, Linux, or something else?

Comment: @WillisBlackburn am using Windows 10

Comment: @mat did my answer below help? You may need to call the script `chrome_reloader.cmd` or something like that on Windows and leave off the `#!/bin/bash` line but it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get to work with the help of some third-party components.

When you call Rscript's `browseURL` function, it's just running whatever program it thinks is the browser and passing it your URL. You can tell it to use whatever "browser" you want:

```
browseURL("file:/path/to/my/file.html",
          browser = "/path/to/chrome_reloader.sh")
```

You can use the [Chromix Too](https://github.com/smblott-github/chromix-too) package to control Chrome. You will have to install a few things, but it's easy and only takes a few minutes:

1. Install the Chromix Too extension from the Chrome web store.
2. Install the latest version of NodeJS.
3. Use `npm` (installed with NodeJS) to install Chromix Too.
4. Run the Chromix Too server.

Now you run commands like `chromix-too ls` to see a list of all the tabs you have open in Chrome and `chromix-too reload http://some.web.site/` to reload one of them.

Now you can write the `chrome_relauncher.sh` script that just passes whatever URL it gets to `chromix-too reload`:

```
#!/bin/bash
chromix-too reload $1
```

It looks like `reload` only reloads a tab that already exists but won't open a new one. You could use the `ls` command to first check if the tab exists; it looks like `chromix-too ls 'http://some.site/path'` returns success (0) if the tab exists and failure (1) if it doesn't, so you could use that in your script. Or just open the tab manually before running your Rscript program. There's also a `file` command that loads a local file and specifically says it will reuse and reload an existing tab.

You may need to tweak a few things (maybe add the path to `chromix-too` which you can get with `which chromix-too`) but this should basically work.