# Flask - Display Image based on condition

Tags: python, image, opencv, flask, video-streaming

I've created a PPE detector on openCV-Python and I want to display image based on the condition that the person is wearing a PPE or not. Code below opens camera and check if the person is wearing the PPE or not?

```
def generate_frames():
    while True:
        ## read the camera frame

        success, frame = camera.read()
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            image_np, boxes = get_detection(frame)

            if boxes[:, -1].tolist().count(0.) > 0:  # not wearing PPE
                filename = r'\images\cross.png'

            else:  # wearing PPE
                filename = r'\images\thumbs_up.gif'

        return filename
```

Following is the index and image code.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/image')
def image():
    return send_file(generate_frames(), mimetype='image/gif')
```

The `index.html` is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


  <body>
    <h1>Live streaming</h1>
    <div>

        <img src="{{ url_for('image') }}" width="50%"/>
    </div>

    </body>


</html>
```

**Question**

I am having trouble identifying why the image display don't change?

So for example if in the first frame person is wearing the PPE the filename won't switch even if in the next frame the person is not wearing the PPE and similarly the image won't change. The filename remains static based on which condition is fulfilled by first frame.

I tried using `yield` instead of `return` but I get an error
`AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'read'`

**Edit**
Upon refreshing the image do change but I want it to change dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear to me what you're trying to do but I believe the whole logic is broken.

Looks like you'd like `generate_frames` to generate images while looping and those images would refresh automatically in the browser. This is not the way things work.

You need to find another mechanism to refresh. Perhaps an asynchronous call using JS to the route generating the image, or some page [autorefresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711888/auto-refresh-code-in-html-using-meta-tags) mechanism.

Also, in `generate_frames`, I think you'll want to replace `break` with `continue` (and the `else` statement is useless).