# reload PHP page with jquery request

Tags: php, jquery

I have two page . first page HTML second page PHP .
I want from HTML page send Ajax(jquery)request to PHP page and refresh PHP page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="reloadButton">Reload PHP </button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#reloadButton").click(function() {
            reloadPhpFunction();
        });
        function reloadPhpFunction() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "php_page.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: { action: "reload" },
                success: function(response) {
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and php_page.php code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'reload') {
    header("Refresh:3");
}
?>
```

but not working ,please guide me .

I open both pages in two browser tabs, I want when click to Button in html page , php page refresh.

**update :**
In order to raise the issue more easily, I explained it like this, but it seems that I made a mistake.
Detailed description:
The html page has several inputs.
After filling the inputs and submitting the data, it is insert in the database.
php page is admin panel (For security I have to use php file) and  has an html (and JS file) part that reads the data from the database and displays it on the same page .
To see the information entered into the database, I have to refresh the page and I don't want to refresh it.Right now, I am using the setinterval function and Ajax request and it works fine, but I am looking for another method.
**I want after insert data into database (with submit html page) send another request to to php page for read data from database and show data In the html part of the php file without refresh .**

Comment: As has been mentioned, PHP is a serverside language - it runs on the server before the browser receives the rendered HTML. Tow communicate between two windows / tabs AJAX is not the correct technolgy - you should look at either `postMessage` or `BroadcastChannel` on MDN

Comment: The whole point of AJAX is that it _doesn't_ refresh the page! It sends an asynchronous HTTP request to the server in the background, without disturbing the contents on the screen. If you want anything to update on the page after the AJAX completes, you must write JS code in the "success" function to do that.

Comment: But it sounds like actually you're expecting somehow an AJAX request to php_page.php to update a page which is already open in another tab. If that's the case then unfortunately I think you have completely, and fundamentally, misunderstood how all this works. It's unclear how, or why, from anything you might have read online about AJAX, you could have come to the conclusion that this might succeed. Imagine the chaos that would ensue if web applications could automatically update another tab, or even another browser or device, on a whim, with no security!

Comment: If you want to enable real-time, two-way communication between two browser tabs, via a webserver, then you need to use websockets. But that is really a more advanced topic and probably not a suitable topic for someone who is very clearly a beginner in these technologies. For now it would be a lot simpler to just make the target page auto-refresh itself at set intervals - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711888/auto-refresh-code-in-html-using-meta-tags for the solution.

Comment: @ADyson , please read update.

Comment: Thanks for the update, it is somewhat clearer. So...how are you inserting data into the database from the HTML form currently? Is that also using an AJAX request to the PHP script? And how do you currently load the stored data into the HTML file? Again is that also AJAX? We could do with a [mre] of the issue so we have enough context to suggest a solution which fits your current design.

Answer (score 1):

Using `header("Refresh:3");` in the PHP page won't refresh the HTML page that triggered the Ajax request. This is because the browser interprets this header as a response to the Ajax request, not the original HTML page. To refresh the HTML page, use JavaScript's `location.reload()`.

**index.html:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#reloadButton").click(function() {
            reloadPhpFunction();
        });
        function reloadPhpFunction() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "php_page.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: { action: "reload" },
                success: function(response) {
                    // Reload the current page after the Ajax request is successful
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

**php_page.php:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'reload') {
    echo "Reloaded successfully";
}
```

Comment: please read update

Answer (score -1):

In this way, the PHP page cannot reload as the PHP code has been executed while rendering the page.

You could send updates from server to browser using a tool like Mercure.

Let me ask you what's the purpose of that code ?
You could prevent that workflow using another application architecture.

Comment: please read update

Answer (score -1):

Php is a server-side programming language, that means it serves in server and cannot be 'refreshed'. You should implement you refresh logic with client-side tools like jQuery or Js itself. Anyway if you want to do something with Php (ex. a calculation) in server-side then redirect to last page you can you code bellow:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); // In Php, it actually redirects not reload
```

Or

```
location.reload(); // in Js
```

This [document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) helps you about header function.

This [page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-server-side-scripting-and-client-side-scripting/) helps you about the server side and client side of web development